# Display tooltip when mouse movement stop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, tooltip

I have a `grid-view` with merged cells and rows which look like this.

[image]

I am using grid view `mouse enter cell` and `mouse leave cell` events to call the `tool-tip` `show` and `hide` methods.

Problem I am having is, since the cells are very closer tooltip get displayed when I moving across the grid. What I am trying to achieve is display the tooltip only when mouse is stop moving.

Is it possible to capture current state of mouse where I can capture mouse is moving or not.

I have looked at the [Control.MouseMove Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but can I find the current state of the mouse using that.

***Update***

I did try something like this

In `MouseMove` event of the gridview `tooltip.Hide()`

In 
`MouseHoverCell` `tooltip.Show()` but had no luck with it

Thanks

Comment: You could delay the tooltip, so you must stand still for (example) 1 second before it shows up. There should be a property for that in the very tooltip object, but it's eluding me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to leverage the [`OnMouseHover`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousehover) and [`OnMouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousemove.aspx) events.

The `OnMouseHover` event is fired when the mouse stops moving. So, in your case, you can fire this event when the mouse stops, pick up the containing cell and show your tooltip. When the `OnMouseMove` event fires teardown the tooltip and start again.

I hope this helps.